# Is there a way to run a program without the location of the executable file?

Tags: c#

I am looking to run a program (like Chrome for example) from C#, without the location of the executable file.

The purpose of this is to create an application launcher that can be distributed across different computers with programs installed in different locations.

Comment: Can you expand your question to indicate what you've tried so far and the kinds of problems you've run into?

Comment: You should have done a bit of research before posting, but here is a link to a similar question: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/afb5012a-30f1-4b96-9931-a143fd76bab5/how-to-find-path-of-installed-programs-in-c?forum=winformssetup . Google for "windows determine installation path of a program"

Comment: Your question is ambiguous, please clarify. Are you trying to create a program that can start other programs OR you need a way for users to start your program (e.g. shortcut) when installtion path is unknown?

Comment: Using your example, you don't specifically run Chrome. Instead you should ShellExecute the resource (in this case a URL) with the verb of OPEN, which will then use the registered default handler for that resource on that machine - which might be Chrome, Firefox, IE, etc.

Answer (score -1):

One option is adding your folder to the `PATH` (environment variable).

"`My computer -> properties -> advanced -> environment variables -> Path`" and edit path by adding your .exe's directory path.

Comment: I am not sure how this would help him in detrmining the installation location of another program.

Comment: Basically OP wants to run an exe without specifying the (full)path.

Comment: his question is very poorly written. My interpretation is create a program that can launch other programs (from unknown locations).

Comment: That's correct, I've the same understanding. So if he could update the path variable on (all) the machines, Launcher application can invoke this executable without full path.

Comment: @HariPrasad In order to add the path variable, one would have to know the location of the files. The question explicitly says they do not know the location of the files.

Comment: I doubt @rob it mentioned, OP says they want to run program without the location of the executable file. (Just like running notepad from anywhere)